# What is Avast doing with autochk?

Tags: windows, windows-8, boot, avast

I've searched and searched, and can't find what these parameters do - can someone fill me in?

```
autocheck autochk * \aswBoot.exe /M:hexadecimaladdress /wow /dir:"C:\Program Files\AVAST Software\Avast"\
```

Avast randomly added this to my startup, and Spybot informed me of it. I let it go through, but I'm still curious what's happening here since Microsoft doesn't have, or I can't easily find, a complete list of all autochk parameters (Including /wow, /dir, and the backslash deal)

Comment: Ask on Avast forum. They may give you an answer

Comment: Its the Avast startup scanner which is used by Avast to [remove stubborn malware at boot](https://forums.spybot.info/showthread.php?31251-New-data-autocheck-autochk*-lsdelete-aswBoot-exe)

Comment: I figured, but what do the parameters do? Any idea?